# How to push an object into an object?

Tags: javascript, object

So i have a object like this:

`let obj = {'0': {x: 25, y: 12}, '1': {x:55, y:6} ,...}`

Now How can I push an other object like `{x: 12, y: 15}` in to this object?

Comment: `obj[index] = {x: 12, y: 15} `

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Insert your data in the last index (you can get the last index converting the object to array and getting the length)

```js
let obj = {'0': {x: 25, y: 12}, '1': {x:55, y:6}}

obj[Object.values(obj).length] = {x: 12, y: 15}

console.log(obj)
```